# Close all browser tabs from specific site

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When a user logs out on my website I want to close all browser tabs of my website. Is that possible to do?
[browser tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnB3W.png)

Comment: if you mean "tabs", then it MAY be possible using the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

Comment: Thinking about it, you may not be able to CLOSE tabs

Comment: This depends on your use-case. If you're looking for a generic solution for all browsers without extensions it's probably not possible. It could be possible for specific browsers and it's probably possible with browser extensions. If your use-case is a public website and your target group is all possible visitors it's not possible. If your use-case is an inhouse enterprise application and all employees have the same browser and have to install your extension it's (probably) possible.

Comment: In general, (aside from jabaa's caveats above), you (as the website developer) don't control the user's browser. Imagine how annoying it would be if a website closed all the open tabs of that site for you! It has no right to decide whether you've finished with them or not. Nor should there be any need for it frankly, either. What are you trying to achieve with this? What problem do you think will be solved by implementing this idea?

Comment: Just because they logged out doesn't mean they finished viewing all the other content. You _could_ maybe have something which hides all the data in them on logout (e.g. triggered by AJAX or SSE or websockets or broadcast), but not closes them. P.S. yes those are called "tabs" not cards.

Comment: @ADyson My site is only available for logged users and when they logs out others tabs are still open and user must manually close each tabs

Comment: That's up to the user. Or they can just close the browser. It's not your application's problem, really. If you look around the internet, most sites don't care about this, they leave the user in control (as they should be).